# Code Cleanup - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This might be a weird question to ask.. but nevertheless this is my question.

I have a huge Asp.net MVC project with lots of model classes. As the requirement grew, we kept on adding some properties and deleting some. Eventually I ended up having properties which are not referenced anywhere in the project.

Is there any quick way to find out these orphan properties.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this. Right-click on your solution and selection "Find Code Issues".

One of the results is "Unused Symbols". This will show you classes, methods, properties etc., that aren't used.

Comment: You will need solution wide analysis enabled I believe

Comment: Also sometimes resharper can give you false positives if the properties are only used via reflection or other indirect methods (eg. model binding), best to use some common sense rather than blindly removing

Answer (score 1):

I would use [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to assist you with this task. In case you don't want to spend the $349 you can use it for 30days for free. Resharper allows you to analyse the whole solution and highlights obsolete/unused code.